# Application-level back-pressure VS TCP native flow-control

Tags: akka-stream, flow-control, reactive-streams, backpressure

I am investigating why some systems implement application-level back-pressure given that TCP provides native flow control.

I was reading, in particular, [akka-streams](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/scala/stream/stream-flows-and-basics.html#back-pressure-explained) and (an higher level discussion) [reactive streams](http://www.reactive-streams.org/).

**Is it only to abstract out the idea of asynchronous communication out of the network and out of the TCP protocol?**

Other, more precise, questions:

- If the application (say akka-streams app) ends up communicating over TCP, will it fall back to TCP's native back-pressure?
- Does reactive streams implement application-level back-pressure on top of TCP by simply leaving TCP handle it?

Any help and pointer would be appreciated!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the underlying assumption of your question is that TCP is the only external communication within a stream pipeline.

Suppose your stream communicates over several IO channels such as file IO, database querying, and standard output to the console:

```
//Read Data from File --> DB Query --> TCP Server Query --> Slow Function --> Console
```

An akka-stream implementation would provide asynchronous, back-pressured, support **through the entire pipeline**.  Therefore akka-stream has to provided application level back-pressure for calling long-running functions, querying databases, reading files, writing to the console, etc.

You are correct that akka's implementation of the `TCP Server` section of the stream [relies on TCP's "native backpressure"](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-io.html).  From the documentation:

> ...by using Akka Streams you are freed of having to manually react to
>   back-pressure signals, as the library does it transparently for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That's exactly what I meant with "Is i to abstract out the idea of asynchronous communication out of the network and out of the TCP protocol". However, I really appreciate it!